# Creating an empty project and add new modules of Micronaut project in intellj gradle is not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, micronaut

I am switching from spring boot to Micronaut application. but when I use the IntelliJ IDE to add modules in the empty project the Gradle build is not supported in IntelliJ 2020.2.2.

I have the project structure as below

[image]

[image]

The gradle build should appear on the right-hand side of the IDE, but it is not

[image]

Even on the run configuration I don't see the project

[image]

I can see the build.gradle file for both the project

Comment: Multi project builds definitely work with Micronaut and Gradle. 
 We do it daily.  Unclear if this is your issue or not but https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162677 may be related.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have **Gradle** bundled plugin enabled in Preferences | plugins. Then you can add a Gradle module via File | New | Module form Existing Sources and select build.gradle file to import from, see [Import an existing module to the project﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#import-module).

Comment: This is not the case with a single project, for a single project Gradle is working fine. This is when we add multiple projects in the workspace.

Comment: Yeah I have the Gradle plugin enable, multiple modules is not working with Micronaut project, however for the spring boot application it is working fine

Comment: You can import an existing project as gradle form the build.gradle file context menu -> import as Gradle project. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#link_gradle_project